# iOS swift alarm repeat function table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, multipleselection

I am new in swift and I trying to do the function similar with the iOS default add alarm function "Repeat":

[image: The "repeat" cell]

When Saturday and Sunday select it will show "Weekends":

[image: Saturday and Sunday Selected]

Else if only select Monday to Friday it will show "Weekdays"

else if only select certain day example "Monday Tuesday" it will show on the label is "Mon Tue"

if select everyday, so the label will show everyday on the label

Now I only done do on table cell with multiple selection but dont know how to get the value from the selected selection on previous table and display on the label

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
//        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            if cell.selected {
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
    }
```

I try my best ask my question very very clearly. Please give some suggestion instead down my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to maintain elsewhere in your code the state of all the days (an array of 7 booleans, for instance).
In didSelect... and didDeselect..., you can then update the array, and know the state of all the days.

Comment: thank you! i have follow ur suggestion " an array of 7 booleans " and it work great!

Comment: You're welcome! Would you mind to accept my answer, then?